# Office 2007 file icons are showing up as generic icons

Tags: windows-7, icons, microsoft-office-2007

On Windows 7, since few days icons of files and shortcuts are showing up as generic Windows icons. Mainly Office 2007 files, 'Office' shortcuts, Skype shortcuts and few more. I was able to fix issue with the shortcuts of all but 'Office' by using the Change icon option. As a part of fixing this, I also understood that corresponding registry entry of icons were corrupt, so I had to locate the program file manually for these applications. Only for Office 2007 I am not able to fix this as the change icon option is disabled. (I am an Administrator for my computer).

I have tried rebuilding the icon cache more than once and it doesn't help. I logged in as another user in this machine and the problem persists for that user too. So creating a new profile does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a clean uninstall of Office 2007 (Deleted the program folders, then cleaned registry entries using CCleaner). Then restarted the machine, and then installed Office 2007.

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Been there, did all that, no cigar. So I went into the properties for one of my docx generic icon files to be sure Word 2007 was the program selected to open it, and it is. Then I noticed at the bottom of the Properties window where it says Read Only, Hidden, and Archive that Archive was checkmarked. Unchecked it, clicked Apply, paused a moment, Ok became available, clicked that, and voila! Icons restored.